# In Enzyme how to wait for an API call in the componentDidMount method?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, nock

We have a React component which we mount with [Enzyme](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme):

```
const component = mount(<App/>);
```

The component loads data on `componentDidMount` which we mock with [nock](https://github.com/nock/nock):

```
nock('http://localhost:3100').get(`/api/data`).reply(200, DATA...);
```

We want to test the `value` of a label inside the component. However the `value` is only populated after the data is loaded via the fetch call. How can we wait for the fetch call to finish before writing the expect:

```
expect(...
```

Comment: You need to chain a promise that fetch returns. Please, provide the code for the component.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do something like:

```
Promise
    .resolve(mounted)
    .then(() => mounted.update())
    .then(() => {
        expect(label === value); // Just using pseudocode here to denote where to write the expect statement
    })
```

You might still face incorrect behavior here, in which case you can check [this](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/1587) thread